# iOS UserDefaults falls behind saved content

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

This situation is a bit too elaborate to describe in mere words, so I've created a minimal demo project for you to download and run:

https://github.com/mattneub/DefaultsDemo

You will need Xcode 10 to test. This is what the project looks like when it runs:

[image]

The project code will appear to have quite a bit of unnecessary kerfuffle, but that is because I've included the minimum material from my *real* app (a card game) to reproduce the issue I'm seeing. There's a deck of cards and a layout of cards, and the idea is when the user clicks the Home button, we get a notification that the app will resign active, and we save the deck and the card layout into UserDefaults. When we relaunch, we retrieve the deck and the card layout and the user can resume playing.

But it's not working correctly, as I shall explain. And actually *testing* to see the phenomenon is very simple:

1. Run the project on the simulator.
2. Hit the Shuffle button three to five times or so. (If you start to run out of cards, hit the New Deck button. But in my testing, that's not usually necessary.)
3. Hit the Home button on the simulator. This causes us to save into UserDefaults. Look at the Xcode console; it tells you have many cards are in the deck that was just saved into UserDefaults. Remember that number!
4. Back in Xcode, stop the project and run it again, starting again at Step 1. As we launch, you are told how many cards are in the deck that was just retrieved from UserDefaults.

Keep repeating those four steps. What happens to me is that after about two or three cycles, the number in step 4 differs from the number in step 3. We are not getting back from UserDefaults the same deck that we saved into UserDefaults a moment ago!

Moreover, I can say something more about this wrong number: it is the number of cards in the deck that we saved into UserDefaults *on some earlier occasion*. It is as if UserDefaults has become corrupt silently in some way and has stopped accepting new versions of the deck.

To illustrate, I have just cleaned the simulator and opened the project, and I'll run it and tell you what I see in the console (with comments explaining what I did):

```
81 // launch
65
starting fresh 65
62 // shuffle
59 // shuffle
56 // shuffle
saving 56 // Home button
```

Okay, let's launch again from Xcode:

```
retrieving 56 // launch
53 // shuffle
50 // shuffle
47 // shuffle
44 // shuffle
saving 44 // Home button
```

Fine, so let's launch *again* from Xcode:

```
retrieving 56 // launch
```

That's the bug! We've fallen behind; we're retrieving the deck from the *previous* save, not the one from the save we just did. (I can actually prove this by printing out the deck; it has a `description` property for just this purpose, and I can actually *see* that it's the deck from the previous save.)

So the question is: why? I know how to work around it; save into files instead of UserDefaults. But I'd like to know what's up with UserDefaults here that's causing this problem. I *suspect* that one of the objects I'm saving into UserDefaults is causing some sort of silent corruption, but I don't see how that can be, as they are just Data objects.

(By the way, calling `synchronize` changes nothing, and in any case it is deprecated according to the header, even though not yet formally so.)

Comment: That could be it. Since `UserDefaults` saves asynchronously, maybe wait for a minute or two before re-running the app. I just glanced at your code. Try calling `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()` after setting `deckArchive` in `willResignActiveNotification` block. Maybe that could fix it?

Comment: Same behavior here. It's most likely a timing problem (maybe even a bug) which breaks the workflow to update the defaults database. Forcing the update with `synchronize()` and waiting a few seconds before relaunching the app seems to fix the issue. Does the error occur also on a device?

Comment: @Pranay I should have mentioned that calling `synchronize` changes nothing, and it is deprecated (see the header).

Comment: @matt Ah! My apologies. I didn't know it was deprecated. Nonetheless, this seems to be a very strange issue.

Comment: @vadian Yes, same on the device.

Comment: Is this a regression from previous Xcode versions? Did you file a bug report?

Comment: “Is this a regression from previous Xcode versions” @MartinR That’s the question. You tell me! I’ve always treated user defaults in this way, and I’ve never encountered this behavior, but maybe there is something about this project that elicits it. It’s new _to me_, but that’s why I’ve gone to all this trouble, to find out whether I’m just ignorant of some well known limitation of user defaults, or whether I’m doing something that’s flat out wrong. The downvotes suggest I’m just being dense, but no one explains just how.

Comment: @MartinR By the way, I see the same behavior in Xcode 10 on an iOS 11 simulator, so I'm led to suspect that it's just always been this way and I simply never noticed, somehow. Nevertheless it's odd that this matter has never come to my attention until now, even though I've been saving this data into UserDefaults in more or less this same way ever since iOS 4.

Comment: Please check https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/84980, Quinn “The Eskimo!” answer, about decisions to save information using UserDefaults.

Comment: @southfox I totally agree! The example is a toy to demonstrate the issue. In the end, indeed, I did save into a file in my real app. But UserDefaults is still useful, and the phenomenon is still a real UserDefaults issue: if you save something into UserDefaults and if you test that by re-running your app from Xcode too soon, there  may not have been sufficient time for the changes to happen. I now always count to ten slowly before re-running, as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to suggest this entire project is a red herring and that the problem is your *testing procedure*.

I theorize that **UserDefaults saves slowly**: it just takes a really long time for a change to UserDefaults to "take", even *after* every signal has occurred that the change has happened (`synchronize` has returned, the `didChange` notification has arrived, and so on).

Thus, I'm betting that you're just *not allowing enough time* between hitting the Home button and running the app again. To see that this might be so, make the following change: Instead of going directly from Step 3 to Step 4, interpose Step 3a, where you count to 10, *slowly*. Now the bug doesn't manifest itself.

(One could also argue that saving at `willResignActiveNotification` time is just wrong. The time to save is when the relevant data changes! Thus, in the test example, we should be saving at the end of every shuffle-and-deal operation — not when the user hits the Home button.)