# UserDefaults sometimes not retaining the saved value when restarting the app swift 5.1

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, swift5

The following is my code to save and fetch data:

```
protocol SettingsManagerProtocol: AnyObject
{
    var host: String
    {
        get set
    }
}

class SettingsManager: NSObject, SettingsManagerProtocol
{
    private var _defaults: UserDefaults?
    private var defaults: UserDefaults
    {
        if let _defaults = _defaults {
            return _defaults
        }
        else {
            _defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        }

        return _defaults ?? UserDefaults.standard
    }

    var host: String
    {
        get
        {
            print("Get value", defaults.value(forKey: SETTING_HOST) as? String ?? "")
            print(defaults.dictionaryRepresentation())
            return defaults.string(forKey: SETTING_HOST) ?? ""
        }
        set
        {
            defaults.set(newValue, forKey: SETTING_HOST)
        }
    }
}
```

To set the value I am using

```
app.settings?.host = txtHost.text
```

Now the issue is I saved a value and close the app and relaunch it. Now sometimes the value fetched is not the updated one, whereas I have checked the value at the time of same and it is updated.
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Unrelated but the entire private *defaults-dance* is nonsense. `UserDefaults.standard` is a singleton, non-optional, public and available from everywhere. And never use `value(forKey` to retrieve a single value from `UserDefaults`. And by the way there is `string(forKey`.

Comment: @vadian changing value(forKey: ) to string(forKey:) does not make any difference. Still cannot retrieve the exact value sometimes. However if I wait for sometime then the value fetched will be the updated one everytime.

Comment: This code is full of weirdness. Don't use `synchronize` ("this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used." https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize), it seems like that would block certain things while your code waits for the data to be saved. And get rid of the whole `_defaults` bit. It makes no sense.

Where in your app are you getting and setting the host exactly?

Comment: @donnywals  I am setting the host on button click. And getting it's value on app launch. And I have added synchronize just to test whether it works or not.

Comment: “However if I wait for sometime then the value fetched will be the updated one everytime.” That’s the answer. You’ve answered your own question. Wait 10 seconds before relaunching. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52448581/341994