# set value in UserDefaults synchronously

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, uiviewcontroller, userdefaults

I am trying to save boolean in UserDefault in swift.
so when I set value in userDefault, my very next instruction is to switch to view controller and close the current view controller.

so, what is happening now is, sometimes userDefault saves the value in DB, and sometimes it doesn't.
I read documentation from Apple
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults
and found that

> At runtime, you use UserDefaults objects to read the defaults that your app uses from a user’s defaults database. UserDefaults caches the information to avoid having to open the user’s defaults database each time you need a default value. When you set a default value, it’s changed synchronously within your process, and asynchronously to persistent storage and other processes.

so, I guess because in the very next line I open a new controller and close the current one so due to which there is inconsistency.

here is my code

```
func setWalkthroughShown(completionHandler: @escaping ()->()) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: isWalkthroughCompleted)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        completionHandler()
    }
```

I even called UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() so that operation may become synchronous.
even though in the documentation it is clearly written not to use this function.
can someone please guide me where I am wrong? how can I save across all places before closing the current process?

this is the function by which I am retrieving value

```
func isWalkthroughShown() -> Bool {
        return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: isWalkthroughCompleted)
    }
```

here isWalkthroughCompleted is a string and you can see I am using same string for saving and retrieving value

Comment: What do you mean here by "closing the current process?" Are you killing the app? Switching between view controllers should have nothing to do with UserDefaults. Any write to UserDefaults should be immediately seen by any later read to UserDefaults in the same process (i.e. without the app being killed). I would first suspect that your call to `.set` isn't actually running in all cases. I would verify that it is with breakpoints or logging statements.

Comment: Remember that the point of the message you wrote here is that UserDefaults is cached in memory. It doesn't reload the database from disk every time you read, so even if it hadn't written the values to disk yet, that doesn't matter within the same process.

Comment: thanks. let me debug again.

Comment: You have shown two functions but you have not shown any code that calls either of them. Show us _that_ code, please. Otherwise we have no idea how you are testing all this (except that you are obviously testing incorrectly). Possibly your calls are being made in the wrong order, for instance. But we have no way of knowing until you show us.

Comment: actually, i was trying to change the root view controller of window after switching from this view controller to my desired view controller.
so that's why I thought my previous view controller would have no reference in memory so it might get clean by garbage collector so that's why I am saying maybe process change affect it. please correct me if I am wrong. thanks

Comment: First, there is no garbage collector; there's ARC which is very different (in particular, it's deterministic in a way that GCs are not, but also it does not handle cycles, which GCs generally do). The situation you're describing might release the view controller and it might not (you can know by putting a breakpoint or log statement in `deinit`). I would start by proving that `setWalkthroughShown` is being called, and then proving that `isWalkthroughShown` is called afterwards, and gets the wrong value. (And that nothing else ever sets that value!)

Comment: I don't know what "change the root view controller" means, and you still have not shown any of the relevant code. Did you actually want help?

Comment: @matt I was doing work on a client project so he will not allow me to share code. so I will try to make a similar scenario and show you the code.

moreover, this issue arises when I recompile a project (in some cases like 1 out 4 times it occurs and if I don't recompile then I have not seen any error yet).

and definitely bro I am accessing value after saving. I have debugged it in detail. currently, I don't have a real device. maybe in real device error don't occur. 
thanks for your help.

Comment: “this issue arises when I recompile a project” Oh. So just wait 20 seconds between stopping and relaunching.

Comment: @matt if I wait for more than 10 to 20 seconds and then recompile then the error doesn't appear. however, I will arrange a physical device and will test on that as well.

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52447225/ios-userdefaults-falls-behind-saved-content

Comment: @matt it worked. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there was no syntax error in coding.

I was actually testing it in the wrong way.
after submitting for the request of saving data in userdefaults, I was recompiling immediately and as value stores asynchronously so sometimes due to killing of the process I was getting this issue.
thanks to @matt.
for detail [iOS UserDefaults falls behind saved content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52447225/ios-userdefaults-falls-behind-saved-content)